# HttpClient Connection closed in between while data is transferring

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

while getting the xml from server, i am facing an issue, where the the response xml provided by HttpClient GET method is partial. Whereas the xml provide using  browser is full as expected.

The code for the same is

```
        InputStream response = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
        }

        response = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```

following is the output of httpclient debug logs

```
        16:07:24(GetMethod.java:89) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod - enter GetMethod(String)
        16:07:26(DefaultHttpParams.java:150) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParams - Set parameter http.method.retry-handler = org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler@578cef18
        16:07:29(HttpClient.java:322) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient - enter HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpMethod)
        16:07:29(HttpClient.java:373) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient - enter HttpClient.executeMethod(HostConfiguration,HttpMethod,HttpState)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodDirector.java:378) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Attempt number 1 to process request
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:684) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.open()
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:691) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - Open connection to mysite:80
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:976) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1916) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:2071) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequestLine(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1379) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.generateRequestLine(HttpConnection, String, String, String, String)
        16:07:29(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "GET /mypath HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:1031) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:941) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:962) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:2034) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequestHeaders(HttpState,HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1300) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addRequestHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1325) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addUserAgentRequestHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1211) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addHostRequestHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1235) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1163) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addCookieRequestHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpState.java:172) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState - enter HttpState.getCookies()
        16:07:29(CookieSpecBase.java:548) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter CookieSpecBase.match(String, int, String, boolean, Cookie[])
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1262) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addProxyConnectionHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1[\r][\n]"
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:1031) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:941) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:962) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
        16:07:29(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: mysite[\r][\n]"
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:1031) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:941) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:962) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:1000) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.writeLine()
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:941) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:962) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
        16:07:29(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:825) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream()
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1585) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpMethodBase.java:1823) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:07:29(HttpConnection.java:1112) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.readLine()
        16:07:29(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:07:29(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:07:29(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.0 200 OK[\r][\n]"
        16:09:31(HttpMethodBase.java:1785) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseHeaders(HttpState,HttpConnection)
        16:09:31(HttpConnection.java:856) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream()
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:159) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HeaderParser.parseHeaders(InputStream, String)
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:09:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:104) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
        16:11:31(HttpParser.java:73) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "X-DGKeepAlive: on[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Date: Thu, 10:37:29 GMT[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Server: Apache[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1DA9A4C37BD6883B837BA8725E3CCC5D; Path=/mypath[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "X-Cache: MISS from ajay[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ajay:3128[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Via: 1.0 ajay:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(Wire.java:69) DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Proxy-Connection: close[\r][\n]"
        16:11:31(HttpMethodBase.java:1462) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.processResponseHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:11:31(CookieSpecBase.java:242) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter CookieSpecBase.parse(String, port, path, boolean, String)
        16:11:31(CookieSpecBase.java:112) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter CookieSpecBase.parse(String, port, path, boolean, Header)
        16:11:31(HeaderElement.java:193) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HeaderElement - enter HeaderElement.parseElements(char[])
        16:11:31(Cookie.java:108) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie - enter Cookie(String, String, String, String, Date, boolean)
        16:11:31(RFC2109Spec.java:130) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter RFC2109Spec.validate(String, int, String, boolean, Cookie)
        16:11:31(CookieSpecBase.java:368) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter CookieSpecBase.validate(String, port, path, boolean, Cookie)
        16:11:31(HttpState.java:124) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState - enter HttpState.addCookie(Cookie)
        16:11:31(RFC2109Spec.java:243) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec - enter RFC2109Spec.formatCookie(Cookie)
        16:11:31(HttpMethodBase.java:1506) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Cookie accepted: "$Version=0; JSESSIONID=1DA9A4C37BD6883B837BA8725E3CCC5D; $Path=/mypath"
        16:11:31(HttpMethodBase.java:1636) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseBody(HttpState, HttpConnection)
        16:11:31(HttpMethodBase.java:1671) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseBody(HttpConnection)
        16:11:31(HttpConnection.java:856) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream()
        16:11:31(HttpMethodBase.java:2140) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.canResponseHaveBody(int)
        16:11:31(Wire.java:83) DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - <<"#######INCOMPLETE XML#########"
        16:12:12(HttpMethodBase.java:921) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
        16:12:12(HttpMethodBase.java:929) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should close connection, using HTTP/1.0
        16:12:12(HttpConnection.java:1147) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.close()
        16:12:12(HttpConnection.java:1214) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
        16:12:12(HttpConnection.java:1173) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.releaseConnection()
        16:12:12(HttpConnection.java:1177) DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
```

When the same url is fetched through browser, it works. Headers of request are following
Browser Response Headersview source

```
        Content-Encoding    gzip
        Content-Type    text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
        Date    Thu, 20 Jun 2013 11:24:54 GMT
        Proxy-Connection    close
        Server  Apache
        Vary    Accept-Encoding
        Via 1.0 ajay:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
        X-Cache MISS from ajay
        X-Cache-Lookup  MISS from ajay:3128
```

Browser Request Headersview source

```
        Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
        Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
        Connection  keep-alive
        Cookie  JSESSIONID=6265E9445BB5CB5EF2594A9BEC19B119
        Host    mysite
        User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
```

Can anyone explain where is the issue, in the httpclient calling code or some other at server side and how to correct that?
Thanks in advance.

The exception is thrown while parsing the response

```
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStreamOfResponse);
```

exception is

```
    [Fatal Error] :2:1: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Comment: `        16:11:31(Wire.java:83) DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - <<"#######INCOMPLETE XML#########"
` think your sending an incomplete/invalid XML in the request.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma, i replaced the hundred lines of incomplete xml with this text for ease. :)

Comment: the response you got was `<<"#######INCOMPLETE XML#########"`, this is something with the server handling the request, you need to check the   data you are sending, also it would be useful if you  check the server logs to know what went wrong,

Comment: The response you are getting back appears to be gzipped.  Are you sure that you are handling that correctly?

Comment: @cmbaxter, the gzipped headers are of firefox browser, and its working over there. & i can't see gzip in httpclient logs.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code, like where it is running into the issue with the incomplete xml?

Comment: Okay, before parsing the response stream, can you print out the response body via `getResponseBodyAsString()`?  I want to see the xml you are about to parse.

Comment: See my comment above your last one

Comment: sorry about that. but i can see that xml is not ending with the tag with which it is starting. And exception also says so. It appears like  some part of it is left at end.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the server is chunking your response but for some reason not indicating that in the response headers.  Maybe try simulating the browsers request header of `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` and see if having the response gzipped fixes things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved the issue, setting the following header worked for me.

```
method.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

and

```
postResponse = IOUtils.toString(new GZIPInputStream(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
```